# Autoit Java argument in run command through $chosen variable

Tags: java, autoit

I made a combo:

```
$Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Java Memory", 24, 872, 145, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M")
```

Then I added something to read it:

```
$chosen = GUICtrlRead($Combo1)
```

Then I made a run command and put $chosen in it:

```
Run ("java -jar spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar " & $chosen, "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\KnarCraft 2013")
```

When I don't choose an option in the drop down list, it starts. When I do, it comes a window that disappears instantly, but it shows all valid parameters so therefore something is wrong in the way it reads it. I think it has something to do with the - but I don't know how i should do it. I tried using a - and then the variable, but then it reads it as -$chosen instead of "-" + "choice in $chosen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First off, the order of your java command line I believe is important, and so the -Xmx option should come after the "java" and before the "-jar" tokens.
- Next, I wonder if you're trying to use too much memory. Have you considered testing this with smaller values?

For example:

```
$Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Java Memory", 10, 10, 142, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
GUICtrlSetData(-1, "-Xmx100M|-Xmx200M|-Xmx400M|-Xmx800M|-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M")
```

Then see if any of the smaller numbers work and if the larger numbers break the program.

My test program:

AutoIt program, MyFoo.au3:

```
#include <ComboConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    Local $msg
    GUICreate("My GUI combo")  ; will create a dialog box that when displayed is centered

    $Combo1 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Java Memory", 10, 10, 142, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
    GUICtrlSetData(-1, "-Xmx100M|-Xmx200M|-Xmx400M|-Xmx800M|-Xmx1024M|-Xmx2048M|-Xmx3072M|-Xmx4096M")

    GUISetState()

    ; Run the GUI until the dialog is closed
    While 1
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        If $msg = $Combo1 Then
            $chosen = GUICtrlRead($Combo1)
            $runString1 = "java " & $chosen & " -jar MyFoo.jar"
            $runString2 = "java -jar MyFoo.jar " & $chosen
            ConsoleWrite($runString1 & @CRLF)
            Run($runString1)
        EndIf

        If $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then ExitLoop
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

Java test program, MyAutoItFoo.java. Of course this was jar'd first:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyAutoItFoo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
      long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
      String heapString = String.format("Heap Size = %H; Max Heap = %H", 
            heapSize, heapMaxSize);
      System.out.println(heapString);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, heapString);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tested a bit and figured out that it was somrthing with what was first and last and stuff. I haven't checked if the program gets it ram, but it has to be one of the desired amounts of ram for it to work. It had nothing to do with it trying to take too much ram.  The solution was:    Run("java " & $chosen & ' -jar "E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\KnarCraft 2013\spigot-1.6.2-R0.1.jar"',"E:\Spill\Alle spill\Minecraft\KnarCraft 2013") Thanks @hovercraft